# how to set inflate for view in list adapter when hide and show buttons

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm trying to make adapter for listview that make some friends items with buttons , if the user is friend i will hide the button "add" if not i will show the button , adapter run normaly and when i press on button add at any item will change the background for this button , but when i scroll the listview the button for next or previous item will shown, whats wrong

for more expalnation see this photo[image]

```
package com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;
import com.InternetPlus.Controls.CircleBitmapDisplayer;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.MyApplication;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.R;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.SplashAtivity;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Model.AddCircleResponseModel;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Model.FriendRequest_ResponseModel;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Model.New_circle_model;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Model.OtherUserModel;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Model.UserCirclesModel;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.ParseJson;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.WebServiceInterface;
import com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.WebServiceTask;
import com.google.android.gms.internal.oc;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
public class ListFreindsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
ArrayList<OtherUserModel> OtherUsers;
Bitmap avatarman, avatarwoman, Addfriendbitmap,
        friendrequestsentbymebitmap, friendrequestSentbyhimbitmap,
        unblock_bitmap, friend_bitmap;
AddCircleResponseModel addCircleResponseModel;
FriendRequest_ResponseModel friendRequest_ResponseModel;
MyApplication application;
String friend_status;
ListView listview_circles;
AddnewFriend_List_MyCircleAdapter adapter;
public static ArrayList<String> circles_selected;
WebServiceInterface SendFriendRequest_webServiceInterface,
        Refuse_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface,
        Cancel_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface,
        Confirm_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface;
List<Buttons> btns = new ArrayList<>();
int selected_pos = 0;

public ListFreindsAdapter(ArrayList<OtherUserModel> OtherUsers,
        Activity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity = activity;
    this.OtherUsers = OtherUsers;
    application = MyApplication.getInstance(activity);
    avatarman = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),
            R.drawable.avatarman);
    avatarwoman = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),
            R.drawable.avatarwoman);
    Addfriendbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),
            R.drawable.add_friend);
    friendrequestsentbymebitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            activity.getResources(), R.drawable.request);
    friendrequestSentbyhimbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            activity.getResources(), R.drawable.user_request_to_friend);
    unblock_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),
            R.drawable.delete_block);
    friend_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(),
            R.drawable.friend);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return OtherUsers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return OtherUsers.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgview_freindprof_pic = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imgview_friend_profilepic);
        holder.txtview_Friend_name = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txtview_friend_name);
        holder.txtview_Friend_gender = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txtview_friend_gender);
        holder.txtview_Friend_age = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txtview_friend_age);
        holder.btnadd_friend = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_add_friend);
        holder.btnCancelFrReq = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_friendshiprequest);
        holder.btnConfirm_frReq = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm_friendshiprequest);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    final OtherUserModel otherUserModel = OtherUsers.get(position);

    holder.txtview_Friend_name.setText(otherUserModel.getUsername());
    String Friend_gender = otherUserModel.getUsergender();
    if (Friend_gender.equals("0")) {
        holder.txtview_Friend_gender.setText(R.string.male);
    } else {
        holder.txtview_Friend_gender.setText(R.string.female);
    }
    holder.txtview_Friend_age.setText(otherUserModel.getUserage() + " y/o");
    Buttons buttons = new Buttons();
    buttons.buttonadd = holder.btnadd_friend;
    buttons.btncancel = holder.btnCancelFrReq;
    buttons.btnconfirm = holder.btnConfirm_frReq;
    btns.add(buttons);

    // show buttn add friend
    friend_status = otherUserModel.getFrstatus();
    if (friend_status.equals("0")) {
        // not friends
        // set Visibility for this btn to visible
        holder.btnCancelFrReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnConfirm_frReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnadd_friend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);           
        holder.btnadd_friend.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.add_friend));
        // btnadd_friend.setImageBitmap(Addfriendbitmap);
    } else if (friend_status.equals("1")) {
        // me sent to user request
        // set Visibility for this btn to visible
        holder.btnCancelFrReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnConfirm_frReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnadd_friend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnadd_friend.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.request));
    } else if (friend_status.equals("2")) {
        // user sent to me request
        // set Visibility for this btn to visible
        holder.btnadd_friend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnCancelFrReq.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnConfirm_frReq.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        holder.btnadd_friend.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.user_request_to_friend));
    } else if (friend_status.equals("5")) {
        // I Blocked The User
        holder.btnCancelFrReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnConfirm_frReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnadd_friend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnadd_friend.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.delete_block));
    } else if (friend_status.equals("7")) {
        // We Are Friends
        // set Visibility for this btn to visible
        holder.btnCancelFrReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnConfirm_frReq.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.btnadd_friend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btnadd_friend.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.friend));
        holder.btnadd_friend.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Listener_for_ButtonAddFriend
    holder.btnadd_friend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // first if not friends
            String friend_ID = otherUserModel.getUserid();
            friend_status = otherUserModel.getFrstatus();
            selected_pos = position;
            if (friend_status.equals("0")) {
                // no friend request , and need to send request
                Show_dialog_choose_circle(activity, friend_ID, false);
            } else if (friend_status.equals("1")) {
                // me sent request and need to cancel it
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd.setEnabled(false);
                FriendRequestUrl = com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.URL
                        .getCancelMYfriend_requestsUrl(
                                application.getfacebookUserID(), friend_ID);
                new WebServiceTask(activity,
                        Cancel_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface,
                        FriendRequestUrl, "GET", false).start();
            } else if (friend_status.equals("2")) {
                v.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.friend));
            }
        }
    });

    // btn Refuse friend Request
    holder.btnCancelFrReq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // first if not friends

            String friD = otherUserModel.getFrid();
            friend_status = otherUserModel.getFrstatus();
            selected_pos = position;
            FriendRequestUrl = com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.URL
                    .getRefusefriend_requestsUrl(
                            application.getfacebookUserID(), friD);
            new WebServiceTask(activity,
                    Refuse_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface,
                    FriendRequestUrl, "GET", false).start();
        }
    });
    //
    // btn confirm friend Request
    holder.btnConfirm_frReq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // first if not friends
            String friD = otherUserModel.getFrid();
            friend_status = otherUserModel.getFrstatus();
            selected_pos = position;
            Show_dialog_choose_circle(activity, friD, true);
        }
    });
    //

    // Show Profile Picture
    String user_photo = otherUserModel.getUserphoto();
    if (user_photo.equals("0")) {
        if (Friend_gender.equals("0")) {
            // user is male
            holder.imgview_freindprof_pic.setImageBitmap(avatarman);
        } else {
            // user is female
            holder.imgview_freindprof_pic.setImageBitmap(avatarwoman);
        }
    } else {
        String Privacy_photo = otherUserModel.getPrivacy_photo();
        if (Privacy_photo.equals("2")) {
            // Profile Picture Visible To All
            Load_profilePicture(holder.imgview_freindprof_pic,
                    otherUserModel.getUserid());
        } else if (Privacy_photo.equals("1")) {
            // Profile Picture Visible To Friends
            if (friend_status.equals("7")) {
                Load_profilePicture(holder.imgview_freindprof_pic,
                        otherUserModel.getUserid());
            } else {
                if (Friend_gender.equals("0")) {
                    // user is male
                    holder.imgview_freindprof_pic.setImageBitmap(avatarman);
                } else {
                    // user is female
                    holder.imgview_freindprof_pic
                            .setImageBitmap(avatarwoman);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Profile Picture InVisible All
            if (Friend_gender.equals("0")) {
                // user is male
                holder.imgview_freindprof_pic.setImageBitmap(avatarman);
            } else {
                // user is female
                holder.imgview_freindprof_pic.setImageBitmap(avatarwoman);
            }
        }
    }

    // User Active status
    TextView txtview_friend_active = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.txtview_friend_active);
    int friend_online = Integer.parseInt(otherUserModel.getOnline());
    if (friend_online == 1) {
        txtview_friend_active.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circletextview));
    } else if (friend_online == 0) {
        txtview_friend_active.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circletextview));
    }

    // web Services
    SendFriendRequest_webServiceInterface = new WebServiceInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            String status = friendRequest_ResponseModel.getStatus();
            if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                friend_status = "1";
                otherUserModel.setFrstatus("1");
                OtherUsers.get(selected_pos).setFrstatus("1");
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd.setEnabled(true);
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.request));

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity,
                        addCircleResponseModel.getError().get(0).getName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackground() {
            try {
                // btns.get(selected_pos).setEnabled(false);
                FriendRequestUrl = FriendRequestUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                Log.i("App Password url ", FriendRequestUrl);
                friendRequest_ResponseModel = ParseJson
                        .getFriendRequest_Response(FriendRequestUrl);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Cancel_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface = new WebServiceInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            String status = friendRequest_ResponseModel.getStatus();
            if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                friend_status = "0";
                otherUserModel.setFrstatus("0");
                OtherUsers.get(selected_pos).setFrstatus("0");
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd.setEnabled(true);
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.add_friend));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        activity,
                        friendRequest_ResponseModel.getError().get(0)
                                .getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackground() {
            try {
                FriendRequestUrl = FriendRequestUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                Log.i("App Password url ", FriendRequestUrl);
                friendRequest_ResponseModel = ParseJson
                        .getFriendRequest_Response(FriendRequestUrl);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Refuse_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface = new WebServiceInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            String status = friendRequest_ResponseModel.getStatus();
            if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd.setEnabled(true);
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.add_friend));
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd
                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btns.get(selected_pos).btncancel
                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btns.get(selected_pos).btnconfirm
                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                friend_status = "0";
                otherUserModel.setFrstatus("0");
                OtherUsers.get(selected_pos).setFrstatus("0");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        activity,
                        friendRequest_ResponseModel.getError().get(0)
                                .getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackground() {
            try {
                FriendRequestUrl = FriendRequestUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                Log.i("App Password url ", FriendRequestUrl);
                friendRequest_ResponseModel = ParseJson
                        .getFriendRequest_Response(FriendRequestUrl);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Confirm_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface = new WebServiceInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            String status = friendRequest_ResponseModel.getStatus();
            if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd.setEnabled(true);
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd
                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btns.get(selected_pos).btncancel
                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btns.get(selected_pos).btnconfirm
                        .setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                friend_status = "7";
                otherUserModel.setFrstatus("7");
                SplashAtivity.loginResopnseModel.setUsercircles(friendRequest_ResponseModel.getUsercircles());
                OtherUsers.get(selected_pos).setFrstatus("7");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        activity,
                        friendRequest_ResponseModel.getError().get(0)
                                .getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackground() {
            try {
                FriendRequestUrl = FriendRequestUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                Log.i("App Password url ", FriendRequestUrl);
                friendRequest_ResponseModel = ParseJson
                        .getFriendRequest_Response(FriendRequestUrl);

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    return view;
}

// Load Profile Picture

public static void Load_profilePicture(final ImageView Imageview,
        String facebookUserID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String uri = "http://newcairo.net/photos/small-" + facebookUserID
            + ".jpg";

    DisplayImageOptions imageOptions3 = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.avatarman)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.avatarman)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.avatarman)
            .cacheInMemory(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .displayer(new CircleBitmapDisplayer(R.color.gray, 0)).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri, Imageview, imageOptions3);
}

String FriendRequestUrl = "";

private void Show_dialog_choose_circle(final Context context,
        final String friD, final Boolean Confirm) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_dialog_add_newfriend_incircle);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    LinearLayout createnew_circle = (LinearLayout) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.layout_createnewcircle_dialog_addfriendto_cirlce);
    listview_circles = (ListView) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.listview_mycircles_dialog_addfriendto_circle);
    circles_selected = new ArrayList<>();
    circles_selected.clear();
    Circles_list_update(false);
    createnew_circle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Add_NewCircle(context);
        }
    });


    Button Buttonok = (Button) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_choose_circle_Ok);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    Buttonok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String Circles_Selected = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected.size(); i++) {  
                String Item_now = ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected.get(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected.size(); j++) {
                    String Item_repeated = ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected.get(j);
                    if (Item_now.equals(Item_repeated)) {
                        if(i != j){
                            ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected.remove(j);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //check if circle id repeated
            if (ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected
                        .size(); i++) {
                    Circles_Selected = Circles_Selected
                            + ListFreindsAdapter.circles_selected
                                    .get(i) + ",";
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
                btns.get(selected_pos).buttonadd.setEnabled(false);
                if (Confirm) {
                    FriendRequestUrl = com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.URL
                            .getConfirmfriend_requestsUrl(
                                    application.getfacebookUserID(), friD,
                                    Circles_Selected);
                    new WebServiceTask(activity,
                            Confirm_FriendShip_Request_webServiceInterface,
                            FriendRequestUrl, "GET", false).start();
                } else {
                    FriendRequestUrl = com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.URL
                            .getsendfriend_requestsUrl(
                                    application.getfacebookUserID(), friD,
                                    application.getLocal(),
                                    Circles_Selected);
                    new WebServiceTask(activity,
                            SendFriendRequest_webServiceInterface,
                            FriendRequestUrl, "GET", false).start();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Please Choose at least 1 circle",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Button Buttoncancel = (Button) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_choose_circle_cancel);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    Buttoncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

private void Circles_list_update(Boolean New_circle_added) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<New_circle_model> new_circle_models = Get_new_circle_models(New_circle_added);
    adapter = new AddnewFriend_List_MyCircleAdapter(activity,
            new_circle_models);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
    listview_circles.setAdapter(adapter);
}

String AddCircleUrl = "";

private void Add_NewCircle(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_dialog_add_modify_circle);
    dialog.setTitle("Add Circle");
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.txtview_dialog_addcircletitle);
    text.setText("New Circle");
    final EditText edittext = (EditText) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.edttxt_dialog_addcircle_value);
    edittext.setText("");
    Button Buttonok = (Button) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_addcircle_ok);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    Buttonok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            circles_selected = new ArrayList<>();
            circles_selected.clear();
            String CircleName = edittext.getText().toString();
            AddCircleUrl = com.InternetPlus.NewCairoNet.Util.URL
                    .getAddCircleUrl(application.getfacebookUserID(),
                            CircleName);
            new WebServiceTask(activity, UpdateCircles_webServiceInterface,
                    AddCircleUrl, "GET", false).start();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Button Buttoncancel = (Button) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_addcircle_cancel);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    Buttoncancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

WebServiceInterface UpdateCircles_webServiceInterface = new WebServiceInterface() {

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        String status = addCircleResponseModel.getStatus();
        if (Integer.parseInt(status) == 1) {
            SplashAtivity.loginResopnseModel
                    .setUsercircles(addCircleResponseModel.getUsercircles());
            SplashAtivity.loginResopnseModel.getUser().setUserstatus(
                    addCircleResponseModel.getUser().getUserstatus());
            Circles_list_update(true);
            Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity,
                    addCircleResponseModel.getError().get(0).getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackground() {
        try {
            AddCircleUrl = AddCircleUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            Log.i("App Password url ", AddCircleUrl);
            addCircleResponseModel = ParseJson
                    .getAddCircleResponse(AddCircleUrl);

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgview_freindprof_pic;
    TextView txtview_Friend_name, txtview_Friend_gender,
            txtview_Friend_age;
    ImageButton btnadd_friend, btnConfirm_frReq, btnCancelFrReq;
}

private class Buttons {
    ImageButton buttonadd, btncancel, btnconfirm;
}

private List<New_circle_model> Get_new_circle_models(
        Boolean New_Circle_added) {
    List<New_circle_model> new_circle_models = new ArrayList<New_circle_model>();

    for (int i = 0; i < SplashAtivity.loginResopnseModel.getUsercircles()
            .size(); i++) {
        New_circle_model new_circle_model = new New_circle_model();
        new_circle_model.setName(SplashAtivity.loginResopnseModel
                .getUsercircles().get(i).getName());
        new_circle_model.setCircle_Id(SplashAtivity.loginResopnseModel
                .getUsercircles().get(i).getId());
        new_circle_model.setChecked(false);
        if (New_Circle_added) {
            if ((i + 1) == SplashAtivity.loginResopnseModel.getUsercircles()
                    .size()) {
                new_circle_model.setChecked(true);                  
            }
        }
        new_circle_models.add(new_circle_model);
    }
    return new_circle_models;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have friend_status values other than 0,1,2,5,7?

Comment: yes but till now no user return with this values
0 NONE, 1 I SENT HIM, 2 HE SENT ME, 3 I DENIED, 4 HE DENIED, 5 I BLOCKED, 6 HE BLOCKED, 7 FRIENDS